# Why doesn't progressbar update when exceeds maximum or minimum value?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

```
        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Player1PointsLife}" Minimum="0" Maximum="8000"/>
```

Why when value exceeds maximum or minimun, it doens't update the UI anymore? How can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
Maybe I was not very clear. I mean, I set in progress bar value = 2000 (all right, updates de UI), then I set -1000 (it's correct, it mustn't show anything in the progress bar), and finally I set 6000 (here must updates the UI, but it isn't updating anymore).

Comment: you have constrained the ProgressBar to max and min value..it wont work for any value less than min or more than max..kind of obvious, isn't?

Comment: all right, but how can I establish that constraint? I mean, in what event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a WPF converter so that if the value is >8000 or <0 it sets the value according to your requirement. Set the converter as follows in XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Player1PointsLife, Converter={StaticResource **YourConverter**}}" Minimum="0" Maximum="8000"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

What should it do? It can't show the progress bar any more empty than fully empty or any more full than completely full. You can fix it by telling the progress bar what you want it to do. If you want it to appear, say, 85% full, set the value to 85% of the way from the minimum to the maximum.

The usual way to do this for a stat in a game is to raise the maximum to the player's current maximum for that stat. If you allow the stat to go over the normal maximum for some reason (say a special power up), you have to decide how you want to display that. Maybe you can change the bar color and raise the maximum to the temporary maximum. Maybe you can add an additional bar to show the "overflow" power. Whatever works for your concept.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear in my post. Please check the update

Comment: You can use [coercion](http://drwpf.com/blog/2010/05/05/value-coercion-for-the-masses/) to limit the value to the valid range. But instead, I'd just never set an invalid value. Wherever you set the value, first make sure it's valid.

Comment: What event I should use to check the value?